# Setting a text value on custom xml properties in Word add-in fails if xml node is empty

Tags: xml, office-js

I'm trying to set text values for custom xml properties in a Word add-in (Desktop). The custom properties in turn are defined in SharePoint and corresponds to fields / content types in SharePoint.

The problem I have is that setting a text value only works if the node already has a value set. If it's empty `office.js` will return an error with `code: 6100` and message `'Custom XML Error.'`.

Given the following custom xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<p:properties xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/metadata/properties" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls">
  <documentManagement>
    <foo xmlns="757d984d-6dab-4bc2-83cc-8319df82947b" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <bar xmlns="757d984d-6dab-4bc2-83cc-8319df82947b">Bar text value</bar>
  </documentManagement>
</p:properties>
```

And given the sample snippet:

```
function setTextExample (theNode, value) {
  const XML_NS = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/metadata/properties'
  Office.context.document.customXmlParts.getByNamespaceAsync(XML_NS, (result) => {
    if (result.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) return

    const part = result.value[0]
    part.getNodesAsync('*/documentManagement/*', (result) => {
      if (result.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) return

      result.value.forEach(node => {
        if (node.baseName === theNode) {
          node.setTextAsync(value, (result) => {
            if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
              console.log('OK, it worked')
            } else {
              console.error('failed to set node text', result.error)
            }
          })
        }
      })
    })
  })
}

setTextExample('foo', 'foo value') // <foo> has no text value, always results in code 6100.
setTextExample('bar', 'bar value') // <bar> has a text value, works fine.
```

I believe this is somehow related to the `<foo>` node having a `xsi:nil="true"` attribute set, since if I remove it (by manually unzipping the file, editing the custom xml file and compressing the file back to .docx), I can set the value.

Any input greatly appreciated on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. Welcome to the painful world of OfficeJS and Microsoft's inadequate documentation.

You're suspicions are correct about the `xsi:nil` part. I had the same hair-pulling experience.

The subtle cause is that as you are using the `setTextAsync` method, your resultant XML would be this:

Pre-update:

```
<foo xmlns="757d984d-6dab-4bc2-83cc-8319df82947b" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

After update:

```
<foo xmlns="757d984d-6dab-4bc2-83cc-8319df82947b" xsi:nil="true">foo value</foo>
```

So, the NIL attribute still remains, but it has a text value too now, hence the XML 6100 Error.

Therefore you need to use `setXmlAsync` method - which is ugly, but the only way forward.
The Word API 1.1 is deficient in providing a more protective environment for us dealing with SharePoint properties.
The Word Preview API has been undelivered for over a year, and frustratingly offers a much cleaner API - so seeing it there is just rubbing salt into our wounds.

Conversely, I had to accommodate setting NIL values in my code. Its just a very poor API.

Full code block:

```
export async function setDocumentProperty(name, value) {
  backstage("SET START: SharePoint Property: " + name + "=" + value);
  return Word.run(async context => {
    Office.context.document.customXmlParts.getByNamespaceAsync(settings.namespace, function(result) {
      var xpart = result.value[0];
      var xpath = `//*[local-name() = '${name}']`;
      xpart.getNodesAsync(xpath, function(nodeResults) {
        var found = nodeResults.value.length
        if (found) {
          var node = nodeResults.value[0];
          var xml = '<' + name + ' xmlns="' + node.namespaceUri +'"';
          if (value) {
            xml += '>' + value.replace(/&/g, "&amp;") + '</' + name + '>'; // the value is tangible
          } else {
            // xml += ' xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" />"; // otherwise handle blank values
            xml += ' xsi:nil="true"/>'; // otherwise handle blank values
          }
          // node.setXmlAsync(xml, { asyncContext: "StateNormal" }, function(setResult) {
          // node.setTextAsync(value, { asyncContext: "StateNormal" }, function(setResult) {
          // node.setNodeValueAsync(value, { asyncContext: "StateNormal" }, function(setResult) {
          backstage_xml(xml);
          node.setXmlAsync(xml, { asyncContext: "StateNormal" }, function(setResult) {
            if (setResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
              backstage_error("SET END: SharePoint Property - " + name + " FAILED with: " + setResult.error.code + SPACE + setResult.error.message);
            } else {
              backstage("SET END: SharePoint Property - " + name + "=" + value + ". Status=" + setResult.status);
            }
          });
        } else {
          backstage_error("SET END: SharePoint Property - " + name + " node not found.")
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: We use several workarounds for dealing with custom xml and the internals of a word document. Since you _can_ read the document data (the complete zip file in binary) you can send that to js-zip and voila you can edit whatever you like with an api that works fine. Let me know if you need more details. Cheers!